# How to install bin to specific folder?

Tags: wget

I need to install the bin artifact inside a specific folder, like `/usr/local/bin`

I've tried the following which doesn't help. Any idea what I miss here?

```
RUN wget http://host:8081/content/build/com/bp-pl/1.0.0/cli-bp-1.0.0-linux.bin | /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: `wget` has `-O file|--output-document=file` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RUN wget http://host:8081/content/groups/build.releases/com/bp-pl/1.0.0/cf-cli-bp-plugin-1.0.0-linux.bin -O /usr/local/bin/cf-cli-bp-plugin-1.0.0-linux.bin
```

Comment: Thanks , since its long line can I split it for two lines ? should I use `\` ?

Comment: You can split by escaping the newline character with a `\\` at the end. https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-17-breaking-up-long-lines-in-your-dockerfile

Comment: one last question , assume that I want to use istead the version `bp-pl/1.0.0/` a env with the version how should I do it ? with `$vers

Comment: Yes you can use environment variables. Why not give it a go and find out for yourself!